# Command Prompt is not showing all my files on desktop and other directories

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

OS - Windows 10

I am facing a really strange issue with my command prompt. I am not able to display all the files that I have on my desktop with the command "dir".

This seem to extend into other areas within my file system as well. None of the files that I am attempting to access are hidden. They are basically my own Word document/Power point slides and PDFs. Usually I am able to reveal all these files after changing my Directory to Desktop with "cd".

Could someone please let me know what I can do to solve this problem ?

Update: This is the directory (Desktop) that I am interested in. I want to be able to see these files on Command Prompt.

[image: Image Link of the Desktop directory]

Update 2: I solved the issue.
My desktop has been pointing to the OneDrive folder. I have now changed the
directory by "Moving" the folder, which also changed the directory.

Thanks for all of your help!

[image: Solution]

Comment: Post the commands you are using and the exact output you are seeing. Then show how it differs from what you have on your desktop. This is not how `dir` works therefore there is a misunderstanding.

Comment: There are two _desktop_ folders in filesystem: `C:\Users\Public\Desktop` (all users) and `%UserProfile%\Desktop` (current user). Check both ones.

Comment: The cmd seems to be pointing to the "All users" instead of the Desktop directory that I see (each time I start my laptop). How can I change this behavior ? Plus, even when I change directory to (current user), I still don't get all the files from the Desktop directory.

Comment: You probably used the option to backup your desktop files when you installed or configured OneDrive. It would've been best to learn the new path and work with it.  Hopefully you are backing your files up somehow.

Comment: Thanks, I will check on this too.

Answer (score 3):

I have a backup for my Desktop on OneDrive, so my Desktop folder shows empty.

What I did was instead of going directly into Desktop, I did

```
cd OneDrive

cd Desktop
```

The folder I was looking for was there. Just a little extra step in between.

Comment: hooo @Jose you saved me... thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

[DIR](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) has switches and options to provide more information. Use the commands

```
DIR /A C:\Users\Public\Desktop
DIR /A %UserProfile%\Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

The updates on the question say that moving the desktop back will solve this. Steps to do so are:

1. Open file explorer
2. Right click on the Desktop folder and select properties
3. Click on location from the top tabs
4. Change the location back to the original location. For me this meant removing OneDrive from the path